# How do I delete a card component using id from a data object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have built a Trello clone using ReactJS, where I have 4 columns called TODO, DOING, DONE and REJECTED, where I can add a card to any column.

In a file I am trying to map over card component and rendering properties from defined dummy data.

What I want to do?

- I want to delete a specific card when it is clicked using the card id in some way.

What is the problem?

- I do not understand how do I delete an entire card object when it matches a certain id.

My TaskboardList.js component :

```
import React from "react";
import TaskboardCard from "./TaskboardCard";
import TaskboardActionButton from "./TaskboardActionButton";
import { Droppable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";

const TaskboardList = ({ title, cards, listID }) => {
  return (
    <Droppable droppableId={String(listID)}>
      {provided => (
        <div
          className="taskboardlist_container"
          {...provided.droppableProps}
          ref={provided.innerRef}
          style={styles.container}
        >
          <div className="sub-heading">{title}</div>
          {cards.map((card, index) => (
            <TaskboardCard
              key={card.id}
              index={index}
              text={card.text}
              id={card.id}
            />
          ))}
          <TaskboardActionButton listID={listID} />
          {provided.placeholder}
        </div>
      )}
    </Droppable>
  );
};

const styles = {
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#eee",
    width: 300,
    padding: "0.5rem",
    marginRight: "1rem",
    height: "100%"
  }
};

export default TaskboardList;
```

My TaskboardCard.js component

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import { Draggable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";

const TaskboardCard = ({ text, id, index, sample }) => {
  return (
    <Draggable draggableId={String(id)} index={index}>
      {provided => (
        <div
          className="taskboard_container"
          ref={provided.innerRef}
          {...provided.draggableProps}
          {...provided.dragHandleProps}
        >
          <Card>
            <CardContent>
              <Typography style={{ fontSize: "1.5rem" }} gutterBottom>
                {text}
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </div>
      )}
    </Draggable>
  );
};

export default TaskboardCard;
```

For further reference to more files, I am attaching my GitHub link. Please consider visiting.
Any help would be much appreciated.
https://github.com/abhinav-anshul/consensolabs

And here is the link for a live demo https://consensolab.abhinavanshul.com/

Comment: Do you mean that you want to remove that specific card from your Redux store? That would just entail adding another element to your switch statement in the reducer.

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do. Any code would be helpful. I'm not getting this really

Comment: any redux todo example .... use `.filter` in reducer

Comment: could you reproduce the code for me? here is my sandbox link for the project https://codesandbox.io/s/github/abhinav-anshul/consensolabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// src/actions/index.js
export const CONSTANTS = {
  ADD_CARD: "ADD_CARD",
  ADD_LIST: "ADD_LIST",
  DRAG_HAPPENED: "DRAG_HAPPENED",
  DELETE_CARD: "DELETE_CARD"
};
```

```
// src/actions/cardActions.js

export const deleteCard = cardId => ({
    type: CONSTANTS.DELETE_CARD,
    payload: { cardId }
});
```

```
// src/reducers/listReducers.js


const listReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  // ...

    case CONSTANTS.DELETE_CARD: {
      return {
        ...state,
        cards: state.cards.filter(({id}) => id !== action.payload.cardId)
      }
    }
```

Then from your delete button, you just need to call `dispatch(deleteCard(cardId))`

Edit: I've updated your code sandbox to implement this https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-golick-7z78k

Comment: I have added my button to my `TaskboardCard.js` component, where I am unable to access the `props` and hence I cannot do the `const { dispatch } = this.props` so how do I access the props in this component?

Comment: When you're using a Function Component in React (see how it's just one big arrow function?) the single argument to that function is the props object. In the 
```
= ({ text, id, index, sample, cardId }) => {
```
the text, id, index, sample, and cardId are the props, which are being destructured from the props object

Comment: Hello I did try but it is not working as expected. I did added the delete action and all as you suggested, it is just the button which is not working. I pushed new changes. Check out my codesandbox link again please https://codesandbox.io/s/github/abhinav-anshul/consensolabs

Comment: I would also recommend changing your data structure slightly, to allow this to be done more easily. I'll update your codepen

Comment: Would be very kind, let me know when you did. The button is still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207043/discussion-between-abhinav-anshul-and-ben).